# Space requirements for Index maintenance

Tags: sql-server, disk-space, index-maintenance

I want to understand space requirements for index maintenance in SQL Server. Basically, what I am trying to find is below:

- Offline index operation with SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON

  1. Space required in User DB data file
  2. Space required in User DB log file
     ​ 3. Space required in TempDB data file
  3. Space required in TempDB log file
- Offline index operation with SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF

  1. Space required in User DB data file
  2. Space required in User DB log file
     ​3. Space required in TempDB data file
  3. Space required in TempDB log file​
- ​Online index operation with SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON

  1. Space required in User DB data file
  2. Space required in User DB log file
     ​3. Space required in TempDB data file
  3. Space required in TempDB log file​
- Online index operation with SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF​
  ​1. Space required in User DB data file

  2. Space required in User DB log file
     ​3. Space required in TempDB data file
  3. Space required in TempDB log file​​
- ​Index Reorg

  1. Space required in User DB data file
  2. Space required in User DB log file
     ​3. Space required in TempDB data file
  3. Space required in TempDB log file​

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a type of `index operation`.

If it is `REORGANIZE` the impact is minimal, but it can be tremendous amount of I/O associated to a process and enormous amount of time.

If you plan to do a `REBUILD` then you need at least the same space in your data file and in a log file as the size of your index. In other words just triple size of your index.

For instance: You have 1TB database with only one table which is also 1TB in size. If you want to build/rebuild clustered index on it you will need additional 1TB+ in data file and 1TB+ in a log file. Impact on TempDB is minimal.

Be aware that there might be completely different results depending on current average page usage and on a new fillfactor. For instance if you have 60% average page usage and planning to fill pages 100% then for 1TB table you'll need only about 600GB of new space.

Also, can have significantly lower impact on Log file when you use Simple logging with 0% fragmentation.

If you don't like my answer, why wouldn't you test all your scenarios with at least 100GB table and post results here?